# Как не использовать запись Hard'ом пути к файлу? Java

Tags: java, файлы, path

Есть файл config.xml. Он находиться в

```
D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\StackExp
```

(Это D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\НАЗВАНИЕпроектаJava отсюда запускаю свое приложение java из папки target)

---

Этот конфиг файл лежит внутри проекта и в коде я явно указываю его путь:

```
File configFile = new File("D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp\\config.xml");
```

Как мне записать путь этого файл таким образом, чтобы при смене пути проекта:

(вот эта часть меняется)

```
D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp
```

программа на java видела где находиться мой config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все конфиги кладут в пакет с ресурсами `resources`, и когда вы пробуете обратиться к нему из кода, вам необходимо в относительном пути указать название модуля/папки подпапки/конфиг : `yourProject/src/main/java/resources/config` либо если конфиг лежит в корне, то указать просто его имя